# How to launch an Android application with voice command?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application as a university project.
the application called talkToMe which take voice commands from user.
Commands like :

1. Calling saved contact or new number.
2. reading new messages
3. adding contacts
4. checking battery status
5. getting current date and time
6. getting current location
7. shifting between silent , vibration ...

i need more features to add to this app to make it more usable, and i wonder if is there a way to launch this app by making a special sound(without pressing its icon)?

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/developing-android-applications-with-voice-recognition-features

Comment: I just finished implementing the first three features and it works. The rest are easier.But I need more features

Comment: helpfull link . But i already done that. I need an answer for my last question in the post